# Best way to determine if a MySQL InnoDB table is in its own file, not in system tablespace

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump

I have a MySQL development server that uses InnoDB tables in some of the databases. It was originally setup with the defaults so all data went into the system tablespace (e.g the main `ibdata1` file). Along the way, I enabled [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) so new database tables get into their own files.

I now want to reclaim disk space from dropping some development databases. I know I have to mysqldump and re-import those databases that are in the system tablespace. What is the best way to determine which ones to focus on?

I don't see anything obvious in the `information_schema` database. I could manually poke around the server with an SSH shell, but I was looking for a more automated or elegant way to do that.

In some older databases, I only see `.frm` files in the database directory, in newer ones I see `.frm` and `.ibd` files. That seems to be the key to know where the data is ...

Sanity Check: Is it even possible to mysqldump half the databases to reclaim space, or do you really have to do every database? There are 54 databases inside this server that use InnoDB tables.

Note: Using MySQL v5.1 on UNIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Yes you have to do every database. I have a [step-by-step process I wrote up back on Oct 29, 2010 in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757) as well as thorough explanation why there is nothing else you can do.

You also asked

> Is it even possible to mysqldump half the databases to reclaim space, or do you really have to do every database ?

You cannot reclaim half. It is an all-or-nothing decision. It is good to keep in mind what lives in ibdata1 when [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is disabled :

- Table Data
- Table Indexes
- [MVCC (Multiversioning Concurrency Control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) Data

  - Rollback Segments
  - Undo Space
- Table Metadata (Data Dictionary)
- Double Write Buffer (background writing to prevent reliance on OS caching)
- Insert Buffer (managing changes to non-unique secondary indexes)
- See the [**`Pictorial Representation of ibdata1`**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

Still, if you want to know which InnoDB tables are in ibdata1 and which are in their own tablespace file (`.ibd`), here is what you do:

**STEP 01** : Run this query in the MySQL client

```
SELECT COUNT(1) InnoDBTableCount
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='InnoDB';
```

**STEP 02** : Collect the number of `.ibd` files in the OS

```
ls -lR | grep -c ".ibd$"
```

**STEP 03** : Subtract those values in the OS

Here is the shell script to compute these things

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'"
IB_TOT=`mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
IB_IBD=`ls -lR | grep -c ".ibd$"`
(( IB_SYS = IB_TOT - IB_IBD ))
echo ${IB_SYS}
```

If you have partitioned tables, then do this:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE engine='InnoDB'"
IB_TOT=`mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
IB_IBD=`ls -lR | grep -c ".ibd$"`
(( IB_SYS = IB_TOT - IB_IBD ))
echo ${IB_SYS}
```

Here is what you get:

- `IB_TOT` : Number of InnoDB Tables in the MySQL Instance
- `IB_IBD` : Number of InnoDB Tables Residing Outside `ibdata1` as `.ibd` Files
- `IB_SYS` : Number of InnoDB Tables Residing Inside `ibdata1`

Comment: Thanks for the counts, but I was looking for info on which databases had their data outside the ibdata1 file, not just counts. Since I have to dump all of them, it doesn't really matter though.

Comment: I guess a `GROUP BY` count could have broken down the numbers by `table_schema`. Yet, dumping everything is an absolute must for shrinking `ibdata1`.

Comment: Only problem is that the math breaks if you have partitioned tables, since that makes multiple .ibd files per table.  To work around this in step 01, I did: `SELECT COUNT(1) InnoDBTableCount
FROM information_schema.tables
JOIN information_schema.partitions USING (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name)
WHERE engine='InnoDB';`

Comment: @JoshuaHuber you are right. You can do it even simpler. In my answer, change `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';` to `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE engine='InnoDB;'`. I'll change it in my answer. Thank you for your eagle eye.

Answer (score 4):

Not relevant to readers using very old versions of MySQL, but on more recent versions of MySQL you can use: 
`SELECT i.name FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES i WHERE i.space = 0;`
to see which tables are in the shared table space and use:
`SELECT i.name FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES i WHERE i.space <> 0;`
to see which ones are in their own files.